# Which way is faster to delete duplicate rows in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I need to find and delete duplicate rows in a table with more than 4 million records. I would like to know which way is the best from speed point of view. I read this article, where several solutions are given, including using GROUP BY, PARTITION BY. But there is no explanation about which one is faster and most efficient.

My table has 23 columns (different data types), no Primary KEY and no FOREIGN KEYS but I was wondering if generally there is a better way to do it.

The article can be seen [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-sql-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-sql-table/).

Comment: The answer to your question might depend on your table structure, data, etc.  Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: If it is of any help, my table has 23 columns (different data types), no Primary KEY and no FOREIGN KEYS.

Comment: In SSMS, you should be able to see the query plan, it shows a tree of the actual operations that will be performed and should give you insight. For instnace, it will show if it uses indexes, etc..

Comment: I work in Azure Data Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not having a primary key for your table is a general bad idea.  Here is one way you can delete duplicates, with the record retained per 23 columns is arbitrary:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, ..., col22, col23
                                 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: At some point PRIMARY KEY  may be added, it is not possible now, but that is not my decision to make. Could you please explain why did you do this - ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)?

Comment: @Yana My solution orders each partition of records, a partition being defined as one or more records having the same exact values for _all_ 23 columns, using a random ordering.  That is, let's say you had 3 records with the same values for all 23 columns.  My solution arbitrarily just retains one of those 3 records, and then deletes the rest.

Comment: Maybe what confuses me is how PARTITION works, compared to GROUP BY for example. When you make partition how many combinations are made between the columns in order to check for duplicates? I am not sure I even ask the question right but this is due to my lack of understanding.

Comment: Explaining `ROW_NUMBER` is really out of scope for the comments section of an answer.  If you understand nothing of my answer, I can't explain it here.

Comment: Row number assigns a sequence number, starting with 1 onwards, to _each_ group of records which have the same value for all columns.  My answer is deleting all records _except_ for the first in the sequence.  So, in the example of 3 duplicates, the "first" gets retained, the rest get deleted.  The `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` just means that the record which gets retained is basically random.

Comment: @Yana: `order by (select null)` is a workaround because SQL Server doesn't allow an empty `over` clause, e.g. `row_number() over ()` which would accomplish the same "random ordering"

Answer (score 0):

not knowing your table structure its not possible to give you a precise answer.
But, why not try out some methods and replace the `DELETE` by a `SELECT` to benchmark them ?

I like to use something simple like this, but my table only holds about 50000 rows so I dont have any performance issues

```
select * from tblTruckCost 
--DELETE FROM tblTruckCost
WHERE tblTruckCost.TruckCostID NOT IN
(
  SELECT MIN(c.TruckCostID)
  FROM   tblTruckCost c
  GROUP BY c.DossierNumber, c.SequenceNumber, c.InvoiceNumber
)
```

The group by is used to get the doubles